# How to pass data from one component to another in Angular without creating new instance?

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I have two components. An object will be added to an array inside Component2. In the smae method, that object has to be passed to an array inside Component1.

I have tried @Input and services, getting help from the solutions I found here. But, these are creating a new instance of the components. The array is getting reset, instead of having new object pushed into it.

What's the fix? Cannot figure out how to use @Input properly with router-outlet.

A generic solution would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Share the code what you had tried so far.

Comment: please share some code so that we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of component interaction via a [service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service).

Component A:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  template: `
    <h1>A</h1>
    <p *ngFor="let item of dat">{{item}}</p>
    <button type="button" (click)="addNumber()">Add Number</button>
  `,    
})
export class AComponent implements OnInit {

  dat: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];
  count: number;
  constructor(private service: AppService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.count = 3;
  }

  addNumber(){
    this.count++;
    this.dat.push(this.count);
    this.service.addNewValue(this.count);
  }
}
```

Component B:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  template: `
    <h1>B</h1>
    <p *ngFor="let item of dat">{{item}}</p>
  `,    
})
export class BComponent {
  dat: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private service : AppService){
    this.subscription = this.service.newValue$.subscribe((res)=>{
      this.dat.push(res);
    })
  }
}
```

Service:

```
export class AppService {

  private newValue = new Subject<number>();
  newValue$ = this.newValue.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // Service message commands
  addNewValue(value: number) {
    this.newValue.next(value);
  }
}
```

Demo: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cabspk)

Answer (score 0):

if you are passing data with the router, you can pass the data with NavigationExtras.

```
import { NavigationExtras, Router } from '@angular/router';
// all the code we know here
export class AnyComponent {

constructor(private router: Router) { }

  passData(data) {
    let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: {
      passedData: data
      };
      this.router.navigate(['whereUGo'], navigationExtras);
  }
}
```

then you catch in the other component with activated route.

https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

Here is the info.